# ncurses pass FIELD

Tags: c++, struct, ncurses

I'm writing a c++ program using ncurses.

Here is a snippet of code

```
int PartEntry()
{

    FIELD *partEntryFields[10];  

    PartEntrySetupForm(partEntryFields);

 }

void PartEntrySetupForm(FIELD *partEntryFields)
{
.......
}
```

If you are not familiar with ncurses, FIELD is a defined as

```
typedef struct fieldnode
```

Here is the compiler error I get:

> error: cannot convert ‘FIELD** {aka fieldnode**}’ to ‘FIELD* {aka fieldnode*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void PartEntrySetupForm(FIELD*)’

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

PartEntrySetupForm takes a `FIELD *` while you're passing it an array of FIELD pointers, which will decay to `FIELD **`.  You need to either pass one element of the array (`partEntryFields[0]`) or change the function to take the array (`void PartEntrySetupForm(FIELD **partEntryFields)`).  You could equivalently declare that as `void PartEntrySetupForm(FIELD *partEntryFields[])`.

Comment: That worked ! Thank you. I'm new to stack and tried to vote this but it only changed from zero to 1 then back to zero.